# What's wrong with image display on Windows 10 PRO?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

As for the image, there's this strange bug happening on the system. The display presentation is kind of blurred or kind of mixed together.

[image]

Just in case this is helpful, my monitor is a LG Flatron L1753T. Although, with other version of the SO (Win 7), this didn't happen.

Sometimes, if I click on it or am able to select some text it goes away. Does anyone have ideas on it and on how to solve the matter?

Comment: Is this a screen shot we're seeing, or a picture taken with a camera? If it's a picture, are the artifacts visible if you take a screen shot then view it on another machine?

Comment: I appreciate your comment! It's actually a screenshot. But as said, it's now solved! And now that it's no longer happening, I can still see it on pic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Windows 10 is pretty good at downloading drivers tailored to your hardware, but in case it messes something up, you can reinstall the display driver manually. Just plain reinstalling the correct drivers sometimes won't work, because there might be "leftovers" from a previous installation. There is a utility which allows you to safely remove these leftovers, called [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/).

Before proceeding, ensure that you have downloaded the correct display driver from the manufacturer of your graphics card (AMD or NVidia or Intel in case of integrated video cards). Make sure to follow the instructions [in the guide](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/ddu-guide-tutorial). This includes going to the safe mode for actual removal.

If the issue persists, it's probably time to start checking for hardware faults - artifacts like these could mean video memory faults, or an unstable overclock.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! It's probably something about the drivers, but I even thought about it after posting the question and looked it up and it was all right, but as the system upgraded, the issue no longer happens! Also, it became unnecessary to check as you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a driver matter. Download the win 10 enabled drivers for your OS/GPU combo and it should be okey.
I highly doubt this has anything to do with the screen itself.

Comment: So, also appreciate your answer! I chose the other one as it was a more thorough one though :) So, the comment on it also applies to you so you can know.

Answer (score 0):

The system now presents the images properly! It was probably the drivers/how the system was acting about them, but after the OS was updated to a newer version it was automatically solved!